# Remove Almost Duplicate Rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have found a lot of examples online of how to remove duplicate rows in a SQL table but I cannot figure out how to remove almost duplicate rows.

Data Example

```
+--------+----------+--------+
|  Col1  |   Col2   | NumCol |
+--------+----------+--------+
| USA    | Organic  |    300 |
| USA    | Organic  |    400 |
| Canada | Referral |    120 |
| Canada | Referral |    120 |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

Desired Output

```
+--------+----------+--------+
|  Col1  |   Col2   | NumCol |
+--------+----------+--------+
| USA    | Organic  |    400 |
| Canada | Referral |    120 |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

In this example, if 2 rows are identical then I would like one of them to be removed. In addition, if 2 rows match based on Col1 and Col2, then I would like the row with the lesser value in NumCol to be removed.

My SQL Server Express code is:

```
    WITH CTE AS(
      SELECT [Col1]
        ,[Col2]
        ,[NumCol]
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Col1]
        ,[Col2]
        ,[NumCol] ORDER BY [Col1])
     FROM table
    )
    DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

This code does a good job of deleting duplicates but it doesn't get rid of rows where only Col1 and Col2 match but not NumCol. How should I approach something like this? I'm a newbie to SQL, so any explanation in layman's terms is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the row numbers restart per `(Col1, Col2)` pair by changing:

```
RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Col1]
    ,[Col2]
    ,[NumCol] ORDER BY [Col1])
```

To:

```
RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
  PARTITION BY Col1, Col1 
  ORDER BY NumCol desc)
```

The `order by NumCol desc` makes sure that the rows with the lower `NumCol` are removed.