# Deleting almost duplicate rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have seen a few different answers for this question, but none really hit exactly what I needed to do in MySQL.

I did find a thread for MS SQL that is exactly to what I need to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602690/remove-almost-duplicate-rows-in-sql) but nothing min MySQL.

Data Example

```
+--------+----------+--------+
|  Col1  |   Col2   | UniqueID |
+--------+----------+--------+
| Peaches| Outdoor  |    1     |
| Peaches| Outdoor  |    2     |
| Apples | Indoor   |    3     |
| Apples | Indoor   |    4     |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

Desired Output

```
+--------+----------+--------+
|  Col1  |   Col2   | UniqueID |
+--------+----------+--------+
| Peaches| Outdoor  |    1     |
| Apples | Indoor   |    3     |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: `CREATE NewTable AS SELECT Col1,Col2 ,MAX(col3) FROM t GROUP BY Col1,col2`

Comment: you should describe your problem in the question, but does your table have a primary key?

Comment: There is a uniqueID in the table...made some edits above.

Comment: Shouldn't the second entry for Apples in the first table have a different UniqueID?

Comment: Also, add some description. Does it matter which entry (lowest or highest ID) gets kept?

Comment: @Mihai - This is exactly what I am looking for! Worked perfect!

Comment: i see you've updated your questions, and this is now different than the MSSQL question. Do you have two uniqueid = 3 like in the unedited question or are them all different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is OK. You only forgot the KEYWORD TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable AS SELECT Col1,Col2 ,MAX(col3) FROM t GROUP BY Col1,col2
```

but the structure can be different from the original table

Do this way:

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable like t;
```

then add a unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE NewTable ADD KEY (Col1,col2);
```

and now copy old data in new table with **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO NewTable 
  SELECT * 
  from t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col3=GREATEST(Col3,VALUES(Col3));
```

so you copy every row and the duplicates tests for maximum

Comment: not sure I understand the "keyword table" comment. Good recommendations though...I see what you're getting at.

Comment: Your example starts with: CREATE NewTable AS SELECT Col1,Col2..... and after CREATE must the word TABLE . CREATE TABLE NewTable AS SELECT Col1,Col2 ....

Comment: Any idea on this error when trying to do the last step here: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Answer (score 0):

Im going to post the answer to the answer provided above so its clear...it is just one simple query:

CREATE NewTable AS SELECT Col1,Col2 ,MAX(col3) FROM t GROUP BY Col1,col2

Just querying max was the trick...so simple.

Thank you!